# Iteration calling stats.norm.pdf() runs slow

Tags: python, performance, loops, scipy

I noticed that the following code takes 0.01 seconds which is too much given that I need it to run around a million times times.

```
mydist = stats.norm(mean, 2)
for x in range(5,30):               
     probplak.append(mydist.pdf(x))
```

Is there any other way to get a similar result (a list of values giving a mean and x values away from the mean giving the standard deviation?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mydist.pdf` can be passed a sequence of values instead of a single scalar:

```
probplak = mydist.pdf(range(5, 30))
```

This produces the result much quicker than using a for-loop.

For example,

```
import scipy.stats as stats
mean = 15
mydist = stats.norm(mean, 2)
probplak = mydist.pdf(range(5, 30))
# array([7.43359757e-07, 7.99187055e-06, 6.69151129e-05, 4.36341348e-04,
#        2.21592421e-03, 8.76415025e-03, 2.69954833e-02, 6.47587978e-02,
#        1.20985362e-01, 1.76032663e-01, 1.99471140e-01, 1.76032663e-01,
#        1.20985362e-01, 6.47587978e-02, 2.69954833e-02, 8.76415025e-03,
#        2.21592421e-03, 4.36341348e-04, 6.69151129e-05, 7.99187055e-06,
#        7.43359757e-07, 5.38488002e-08, 3.03794142e-09, 1.33477831e-10,
#        4.56736020e-12])
```

Using IPython to perform a speed comparison:

```
In [112]: %timeit mydist.pdf(range(5, 30))              # <-- passing sequence
10000 loops, best of 3: 134 µs per loop

In [113]: %timeit [mydist.pdf(x) for x in range(5,30)]  # <-- using a loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop
```

---

Also note that [`stats.norm.pdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf) can be passed array-like arguments not only for `x` but also for the `loc` (i.e. `mean`) and `scale` (i.e. standard deviation).
That means that if you need to run this code for a million
different means and scales, then you could compute
all the `probplak`s at once with one call to `stats.norm.pdf`:

```
means = [1,2,3]
std_devs = [10,20,30]
probplaks = stats.norm.pdf(np.arange(5, 30)[:,None], means, std_devs)
```

returns an array of shape `(25, 3)`. If you change `means` and `std_devs` to lists with a million values, then `probplaks.shape` would be `(25, 10**6)`.

Computing all the probplaks with one call to `stats.norm.pdf` will be much faster than a million calls to `mydist.pdf` in a Python loop:

```
In [117]: %timeit stats.norm.pdf(np.arange(5, 30)[:,None], means, scales)
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop

In [118]: %timeit [[stats.norm(m, s).pdf(x) for x in range(5,30)] for m,s in zip(means,scales)]
10 loops, best of 3: 64.4 ms per loop
```